# Compare value of previous row and next row; create new DF with the rows matching condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare floating point values with each another within one column; I need a function that doesn't produce an error...

The functione should loop through the column and compare each value within the columns previous value and also with the next value and create a new DF with all rows  matching conditions.

I tried a combination of for loops and if statements but I couldn't figure out a code not producing errors.

**Example:**

Condition = True if the value of col1 is high than the previous value of col1 and at the same time lower than the next; all within col1
Condition = True as well if the value of col1 is lower than the previous value of col1 and at the same time higher than the next

The first and last value will produce an error so they should be compared each with a variable called compare_first and compare_last which I will define manually

```
values = [[5.5, 2.5, 10.0], [2.0, 4.5, 1.0], [2.5, 5.2, 8.0],
               [4.5, 5.8, 4.8], [4.6, 6.3, 9.6], [4.1, 6.4, 9.0],
               [5.1, 2.3, 11.1]]

# creating a pandas dataframe
a_df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
                  index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
print(a_df)
```

output

```
   col1  col2  col3
a   5.5   2.5  10.0
b   2.0   4.5   1.0
c   2.5   5.2   8.0
d   4.5   5.8   4.8
e   4.6   6.3   9.6
f   4.1   6.4   9.0
g   5.1   2.3  11.1
```

**desired output - all rows matching the described conditions as a new df**

```
   col1  col2  col3
b   2.0   4.5   1.0
e   4.6   6.3   9.6
f   4.1   6.4   9.0
```

Comment: Is ouput correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @jezreal & @mozway through your code samples I started to research about .le() and .gt() and .diff() and .any() and managed to create a code that exatly does what I need. I AM SO HAPPY to have solved this :D
here it is:

```py
#b_df = a Series with all values matching conditions
b_df = a_df.col1[((a_df.col1.diff().gt(0) & a_df.col1.diff(-1).gt(0))|(a_df.col1.diff().le(0) & a_df.col1.diff(-1).le(0)))]

#keep_index_df if the original index should be preserved (this df is the solution to my question)
keep_index_df = a_df.reset_index().merge(b_df, how='right', on='col1')
keep_index_df = keep_index_df.set_index('index')

#reseted index df
new_index_df = pd.merge(a_df, b_df, how='inner')
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare shifted values for greater prevous or next values with [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and chain masks by `|` for bitwise `OR`, then omit first and last value of mask and set `False` in [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
m = a_df.col1.lt(a_df.col1.shift()) | a_df.col1.gt(a_df.col1.shift(-1))

# @mozway alternative
m = a_df.col1.diff().lt(0) | a_df.col1.diff(-1).gt(0)

df = a_df[m.iloc[1:-1].reindex(a_df.index, fill_value=False)]
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3
b   2.0   4.5   1.0
e   4.6   6.3   9.6
f   4.1   6.4   9.0
```

Comment: `a_df[(a_df.diff().gt(0) & a_df.diff(-1).le(0)).any(axis=1)]` (not posting as it's a similar logic)

Comment: first of all thanks for looking into my problem unfortunately the code is not matching the desired output. Can you see the three rows below the bold desired output? It should be matching that. Also I would need this as a a function with the possibility to manually add a value for the first and last row to be compared and not throwing errors (because there is no value before the first and no one after the last)

Comment: @DataScientistNovice - Can you explian why not matched row `c` ? And why match `f` row?

Comment: @jezrael - yes so row f is matching the condition of having the previous row (e) with a higher value and at the same time the following row (g) has a higher value;  so  e > f < g is true;  the function should output all rows where the value is matching one of the condition; for f the function should check if  e > f < g  |  e < f > g

Comment: @jezrael so the code from the comment outputs e & f & b correctly as  d < e > f                
 and e > f < g     but c is not correct as b < c < d    instead only b is correct a > b < c                  the code from your answer outputs e & f & c so

Comment: @DataScientistNovice - Answer was edited.

Comment: maybe I should remind: only col1 matters the rest ist just random numbers and the code from the comment outputs c wrongly maybe my previous comment was not clear enough

Comment: @DataScientistNovice - Answer was checked? Because seems working correctly.

Comment: @jezrael mozway  thank you once more -> see solution in my answer below :))