# How to return values based on conditions with a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame called m_salary_df as follows:

| Month | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| Jan. | $100 |
| Feb. | $200 |
| March | $200 |
| April | $150 |

How do you return only those months where the salary increased compared to the immediate preceding month?

In the above DataFrame, the return should be Feb. only. Since the Feb. salary increased compared to the Jan. salary.

I've tried different loops but nothing delivered the correct results so far.

Comment: Potentially: `df[ df["Salary"] > df["Salary"].shift() ]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare value of previous row and next row; create new DF with the rows matching condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74612326/compare-value-of-previous-row-and-next-row-create-new-df-with-the-rows-matching)

Comment: Try: `df['Salary'] = df['Salary'].str.replace(r'\$', '', regex=True).astype(float)

df['Month'][df['Salary'].gt(df['Salary'].shift())].to_list()[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the "$" sign from the Salary column to convert it to floating point numbers. After that, apply "diff" to see if the difference is more than 0:

```
is_more = df["Salary"].str.replace("$", "", regex=False).astype("float").diff() > 0
df[is_more]
```